# Summation of a series of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

What will be summation of this Series:
 $$ {}_nC_1 + {}_nC_2 + {}_nC_3+\cdots +{}_nC_k$$ for   $k \leq n$?

Comment: Generally, there is no closed form, a fact which is frustrating to anybody trying to do coin toss probabilities.

Comment: For the special case $k=n$, the result is $2^n-1$.  For the special case $k=n-1$, the result is $2^n-2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment by Thomas Andrews that there is not a "formula" for these partial sums.  However, there is a recurrence that will give you the values of the sums as handily as any formula.  S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + S(n-1,k).

Here is a code that returns S(n,k) in Mathematica:  f[n_, k_] := f[n, k] = f[n - 1, k] + f[n - 1, k - 1]; f[n_, 0] = 1;f[n_, n_] = 2^n;

For example S(30,20) = 1,050,777,737.

Also, you can visit Sloane's OEIS for more information about these numbers.